# How do I map my HashMap in the ActionBean with the form on the JSP?

Tags: jsp, hashmap, stripes

I am using Stripes. My Action bean has a HashMap which has id(String) and quantity(int). On the JSP I am submitting a Form, the id and the quantity I want to map to the HashMap so that all the ids and quantity on the form are 'put' in the HashMap. How do I do it?

I have done something like -

In the ActionBean(with getter and setter) -

```
private Map<String, Integer> productVariantMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

on the JSP -

```
<s:useActionBean
beanclass="com.hk.web.action.core.b2b.B2BAddToCartAction" var="atc"/>
<s:useActionBean>
```

and I am picking up the values in the onsubmit through a loop and putting the values like

```
 ${atc:productVariantMap.put(id, quantity)};
 or 
 $(atc.productVariantMap.put(id,quantity)};
```

None of these works. Suggest me a way to map my HashMap or add these values as per my requirement.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is described in [the documentation](http://www.stripesframework.org/display/stripes/Indexed+Properties#IndexedProperties-IndexedPropertieswithMaps%28andarbitrarykeytypes%29). Have a getter and a setter for your map in yhe action bean, and have input fields in the HTML form named like `productVariantMap['foo']` (foo being a key of the map).

So for example, a form containing the following input fields will populate the map with 1 for the key `"foo"`, and 2 for the key `"bar"`:

```
<input type="text" name="productVariantMap['foo']" value="1"/>
<input type="text" name="productVariantMap['bar']" value="2"/>
```

Comment: Actually I have to save both key and value from the form. So, cannot have these foo and bar. How to do then? I need to use the put function to put the key and value in the Map, the values of which is passed via the form. Any alternative approach you might suggest?

Comment: Please elaborate. What would the form look like? How would the user enter key and values?

Comment: I have a table in which I have productId and quantity in each row which is to be input and I want to save all of them in a map. So I need to call put(id,qty) and then add. Now can it be done through what you have suggested?

Comment: Not without using JavaScript. But you could simply use two parallel lists instead: one list containing the product IDs, and another own containing the quantities.